# Why don't these Azure DevOps predefined variables work in a pipeline build?

Tags: azure-devops

Given the following yml snippet, the Azure DevOps Pipeline [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) used in this script don't get 'picked up'.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
  <snipped>
pr:
  autoCancel: false
  paths:
    include:
  <snipped>

steps:
# Remove this task once .NET Core 2.2 is added to hosted agent.
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '2.2.100'

- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration) -p:Version=$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth).$(Rev:r)
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  workingDirectory: 'src/<snipped>'
```

Notice how i'm trying to set the version property of a `dotnet build`:

```
dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration) -p:Version=$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth).$(Rev:r)
```

BUT! when I manually define the build name .. and then reference that variable .. it works!

```
name: $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth).$(Rev:r)

  <snipped>

- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration) -p:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber)
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  workingDirectory: 'src/<snipped>'
```

is this a bug with Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The variables `$(Year:yyyy)` `$(Month)` `$(DayOfMonth)` `$(Rev:r)` are not part of the regular pre-defined build variables, as you can see, they do not exist in the list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

You can use those variables **only** in the Build number format (`name` in the YAML).

So just you did, you can use them there and during the build use the variable `Build.BuildNumber` to get the value.

Comment: AH! they are only available to when generating the build name. AH! gotcha! ta.